# Kendo grid. Update only current row in popup, even if other was changed

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

For example I have many many rows which contains 2 columns: checkbox and input, and popup window with editing. In DataSource I have 'Update' event, which call method for updating from controller.

Question: Is it possible to make such situation: User check checkbox on first row -> open popup for second row -> submit changes. Only second row should be updated, not all.

I want pass to server item only from current row. Actual result is that all changed rows passed to method 'Update'

This situation appears because in my application combined "incell" and "popup" editing for Kendo Grid.

Comment: Could you post some code for better understanding a problem?

Comment: Why are you allowing the user to make "changes" outside of your popup? Could you possibly make it to where if the user wants to check/uncheck the checkbox they have to go to the popup to do so?

Comment: @Supersnake: extended functional. There are exist inline editing mode, and popup editing. In my application these 2 methods are combined.